# Как называется алгоритм оптимизации последовательности изменений множества?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть ли такой описанный алгоритм, который оптимизирует последовательность изменений множества? В отличии от алгоритма поиска растояния Левенштейна, у меня нет ни начального множества, ни конечного. Есть множество изменений, которое нужно оптимизировать, которое после может применяться уже к изменяемым множествам.

Вот для примера такая последовательность действий:

```
1. insert to 5: A
2. insert to 6: B
3. delete from 5: A
4. delete from 4: C
```

Действия 1 и 3 лишние. Действие 4 подразумевает, что в исходном множестве в позиции 4 должна быть буква C, т.е. не каждое множество действий применимо к любому исходному множеству, но это уже детали. После оптимизации должно остаться:

```
1. insert to 5: B
2. delete from 4: C
```

Т.е. исходные 1 и 2 удалились, и соответственное для исходного действия 3 поменялась позиция.

Есть ли что-либо подобное где-нибудь?

Comment: Не сложно придумать начальное и конечное множества подходящие под последовательность действий. К ним примените Левенштейна что бы найти кратчайший переход.

Comment: Как вариант. Берем пустое множество, и применяем к нему эту последовательность действий. Если вдруг оказывается, что такого элемента, с которым требуется выполнить действие, нет — добавляем его в исходное множество. Результат — получаем минимально необходимое исходное множество (должно быть подмножеством для применимости действий) + что из этого подмножества должно получиться. Надо только учесть, что могут быть варианты невозможных действий - например, удалить элемент A, а позже заменить A на C, например... (Кстати, надо еще и решать, вдруг по условию так можно - замена отсутствующего...)